# ChartJS vertical bar chart - measure percentage of the data in each column based on a specified max

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

I hope my title is well enough formulated, i am very new to chartJS actually just started i read the entire documentation multiple times and have done many simple to medium difficulty examples.

I am trying to graph the results of a test by categories, for example a Math test includes the categories: Algebra, Calculus, Analysis, Geometry , Combinatorics. I am making a graph in which each bar/column is a category and the data is the amount of correct questions from this category, as my max for a bar/column i want to have the maximum amount of questions in a given category, so no matter what number i plug this number will always be my max so 100%, so if i have 10 questions for Algebra in the test and i answer 7/10 correctly i want to see the bar be at 70% since this is the amount of correct questions from this specific category, but if i have 4/10 in Calculus this specific bar/column should be at 40%.

I hope my explanation was clear enough, i have all the data i need to achieve this ready to go, i just do not know how to exactly execute this no matter how much i research.

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post the code you already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution heavily depends on the format of your base data. It could for example be defined as follows:

```
const testResults = [
  { category: 'Algebra', totalQuestions: 10, correclyAnswered: 7 },
  { category: 'Calculus', totalQuestions: 12, correclyAnswered: 9 },
  { category: 'Analysis', totalQuestions: 8, correclyAnswered: 5 },
  { category: 'Geometry ', totalQuestions: 10, correclyAnswered: 10 },
  { category: 'Combinatorics ', totalQuestions: 9, correclyAnswered: 5 }
];
```

In this case, the chart `data` could be generated in the following way:

```
const data = {
  labels: testResults.map(o => o.category),
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Test Results',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: testResults.map(o => (100 / o.totalQuestions * o.correclyAnswered))
    }
  ]
};
```

Then you would also have to define chart `options` to make sure tooltips and labels are properly formatted and the x-axis spreads full with between 0 and 100 %.

```
const options = {      
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
        return label + ': ' + tooltipItem.xLabel.toFixed(0) + '%';
      }
    }
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        stepSize: 10,
        callback: value => value + '%'
      } 
    }]
  }
}
```

The chart itself would be defined as follows:

```
<HorizontalBar 
  data = { data } 
  options = { options } 
/>
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lna6o2?file=Hello.js).